# Divide a database value by 10 and updating the web server

Tags: php, codeigniter, webserver

I found this php code for our website that reports machines values from the machine database onto the website.

```
function get_cycledata($serial)
    { 
        $rows=array();
        $this->db->select('cycle_timestamp,cycle_18_INT,cycle_03_INT,cycle_06_INT,cycle_08_INT,cycle_17_INT');
        $this->db->from('cycles');
        $this->db->where('cycle_serial', $serial);
        $this->db->order_by("cycle_timestamp","desc"); 
        $q = $this->db->get();
        foreach($q->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $row['cycle_timestamp'] = $this->reports_model->time_convert($row['cycle_timestamp']);
            $rows[]=$row;
        }
        return $rows;   

    }
```

I want to edit the values "cycle_06_INT" and "cycle_08_INT" by dividing the int values by 10 before displaying it onto the website reporting page. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use expressions in your select list:

```
$this->db->select('cycle_timestamp,cycle_18_INT,cycle_03_INT,cycle_06_INT/10,cycle_08_INT/10,cycle_17_INT');
# Here ------------------------------------------------------------------^-----------^
```

Comment: I tried that but while reloading the page, it returned an error saying:

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'cycle_06_INT/10' in 'field list'

SELECT `cycle_timestamp`, `cycle_18_INT`, `cycle_03_INT`, `cycle_06_INT/10`, `cycle_08_INT/10`, `cycle_17_INT` FROM (`cycles`) WHERE `cycle_serial` = '0CSA000002' ORDER BY `cycle_timestamp` desc

Filename: models/reports_model.php

Line Number: 63